# Opening DLG box present in MFC using python

Tags: python, c, dll, mfc, extern

I am trying to open a DLG box present in MFC using python. I have tried two methods within extern C.

1. 1st method

```
extern "C"
{   DLLEXPORT void open_dlg_32k_trim()
  { 
    IDD_32KHZ_CTRL_CODE *obj=new IDD_32KHZ_CTRL_CODE;
    //customer function to store first dialig object
    obj->Create(IDD_32K_CONTROL,obj);
    obj->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
   }
 }
```

2. 2nd method

```
extern "C"
{   DLLEXPORT void open_dlg_32k_trim()
    { 
      IDD_32KHZ_CTRL_CODE ob;
      ob.DoModal();
    }
}
```

The code compiles successfully on dll side. But while calling the function from the python the code it is throwing error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZrGl.png)

Can you help me out where I am doing wrong and what is the first thing to look into .

Comment: You're dereferencing a null pointer. Since the code is entirely incomplete, it's down to guessing. I'm guessing that you're failing to properly [manage module state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/managing-the-state-data-of-mfc-modules).

Comment: Sorry , I couldn't get you. My main aim is to open a dialog box present in mfc using dll in python.

Comment: The dialog resource is compiled into the DLL. You'll have to tell the code *where* to look for the dialog resource. That's why need to manage the module state when calling into (and returning from) a DLL.

Comment: Use a Debugger and look where the crash occurrs.

Comment: since the issue is happening in python I don't know any possible idea for debugger can you recommend which one can I use